# Django admin changelist - restrict where field is NULL

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm setting up a new Django app and need to customize the Admin for a given table by restricting the records where a field is NULL.  Basically a built-in, permanent filter.

Seems like changelist_view needs to be overridden, but I'm uncertain what that change would look like.

There's no code to be included as I'm not overriding changelist_view right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override default manager, but it has a drawback that you'll have to explicitly specify original manager in all your queries:

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(MyManager, self).get_query_set().filter(my_field__isnull=False)

class MyModel(models.Model):
   objects = MyManager()
   all_objects = models.Manager()

MyModel.all_objects.all()    # all objects including those having my_field=None
```

Comment: Thanks Antony. This example applies to ALL objects, correct? MyManager and MyModel would retrict all queries with that filter?

Comment: django admin uses the manager tied to `.objects`. You can use whichever manager you like (either `objects` or `all_objects`). In certain cases (like "reverse" lookup) `objects` is used automatically in your queries, so if you use this model in your code often, search another solution. This one is more like a quickfix.

Comment: Thanks Antony. Going to write my own admin page instead.

Comment: Welcome. Drop a line here if you come up with an elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a good way to do this at present - there is in fact an open ticket on Django requesting the ability to customise what `QuerySet` gets used for the admin views - see  ticket [#10761](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10761). [Antony's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059840/django-admin-changelist-restrict-where-field-is-null/2059890#2059890) will work in the short term, but you may have to wait until that ticket is resolved for a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use limited queryset manager as objects. For ModelAdmin I've copied **queryset()** from django/contrib/admin/options.py and changed _default_manager by mine unlimited queryset manager. Simple!